# Does DataNucleus (JPA) support a sequence-per-entity when using an inherited table generator for @Id?

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

Basically, I'd like to have a @MappedSuperclass that defines surrogate id generation for all extending entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

If I have 3 types of concrete entities, EntityA, EntityB, and EntityC, I'd like to see a SEQUENCE_TABLE that looks like the following:

```
SEQUENCE_NAME  |  NEXT_VAL
--------------------------
EntityA           11
EntityB           31
EntityC           101
```

...with each sequence being independent and used only for its corresponding entity. Is such a thing easily possible using DataNucleus? Ideally I'd like to avoid declaring a @TableGenerator for each @Entity. Hibernate offers this behavior using a "prefer_sequence_per_entity" property, but I otherwise prefer DataNucleus for a few other features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : no.

More complicated answer : no, but somebody could contribute such a thing if they needed it. That said, it is a minority interest feature and has significant drawbacks in that there would be many situations where it couldn't be used, thinking particular where there were relations to the BaseEntity, what inheritance was chosen for the BaseEntity, and the need to be able to determine the related object

Comment: Yeah, I suppose a sequence for every entity class might not always be reasonable, but when there's a single common `@MappedSuperclass` for just about every `@Entity` in the application, it'd be nice to defer the type detection at least one level in the class hierarchy (perhaps targeting the base table). Anyway, I appreciate the response and a single Long sequence is probably sufficient for most applications.